# Python C extension - maintaining state

Tags: python, python-c-extension

I need to write a Python extension in C that I will use to:

1. perform CPU-intensive initialization on a file;
2. make multiple function calls that rely on the initialized data to return results to me; and
3. free memory when I'm done

One solution is to implement a "state holder" class in Python. When I call the initialization in C, it returns me the initialized data that I will store in my Python state object. Then every time I need to do step (2), I would pass it to the C function. But this seems very inefficient with all the data shuttling/interfacing occurring between the Python side and the C side.

If possible, I would like to maintain the state using a state object on the C side. The initialization call from the Python side would return not all the initialized data, but just an ID so it can reference the C state object when it needs to during subsequent calls.

**How would I go about maintaining state on the C side?**

Comment: I think you're optimizing out the wrong part. Passing the object back and forth is nothing—it's just a pointer. It's converting back and forth between, e.g., `PyInteger` and `int` over and over that's going to kill you. So create a C struct with normal C state (`int`s and such), and a Python wrapper that takes care of managing the lifetime of the struct but doesn't see any of the data.

Comment: To do things the way you actually asked, you could create a hash table, binary tree, or array of structs in C, and pass the hash key, tree key, or array index to Python to use as the id… but more simply and obviously, if you're never copying the state struct around, just cast the pointer from `struct State *` to `intptr_t` and use that as the id.

Comment: Look into Cython. You can make extension classes that talk to C code with minimum hassle.

Comment: @kwatford: Very good hint in general, although I don't think it directly answers the OP's question. Indirectly, on the other hand, it may be possible to replace the whole C extension (or at least the top layer) with Cython, making the question moot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I'll answer the question you actually asked.

Create a `struct State` in C, just as you would if Python weren't involved.

If you're not going to be copying these around (you only pass them by `struct State *`), then you can just do `(intptr_t)theStatePtr` to get an id for Python. Of course you do need to be careful that the lifetime of the Python object never extends past the lifetime of the C object, but that's doable.

If you do need to copy/move the struct around for some reason, or you need more help managing state (e.g., treating the Python ids as weak references), pick the appropriate collection (hash table, tree, array, etc.) for your use case, then pass the key to Python as an id.

However, I think you may be optimizing the wrong part here. Passing the object back and forth is nothing—it's just a pointer copy. Refcounting may be an issue, but it rarely is, and the benefits you get from lifecycle management are usually worth it. The part that may kill performance is your C code continually converting a bunch of Python integers to C `int`s, etc. If this is your problem, just create a C struct with the C state, and wrap it in a Python object that doesn't expose any of the internals into Python.

Finally, do you actually need any optimization here at all? If you're doing CPU-intensive work, I'll bet the real work so completely overshadows the cost of the Python object access that the latter won't even show up in profiling. If you haven't profiled yet, that's absolutely positively the first thing you should do, because the right answer here may well be "don't bother doing anything".

Taking that a step further: If you're only writing the C code in C for optimization, are you sure you even need *that*? Dealing with memory management in C is annoying and error-prone, dealing with it in a C extension module for Python even more so, doing it for the first time when you don't already know how it works is almost a guaranteed recipe for spending all your time chasing down segfaults and leaks rather than writing your actual code. So, I would try the following in order, profiling each and only moving down the list if it's too slow:

- Just write the algorithm in Python, and use your existing CPython interpreter.
- Make sure you've got an optimal algorithm.
- Try PyPy instead of CPython.
- Get [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html) and try compiling your Python code with as few changes as possible.
- Modify your code to take advantage of Cython features like static types, direct calls to C functions, etc., as appropriate.
- Write the lower-level code in C, the mid-level code (the stuff that tracks your state objects and presents a wrapper to Python) either in Cython, or in Python with `ctypes`.
- Write the whole lower and mid level in C, using your favorite interface mechanism. Which is *still* probably not the native C API, unless you've got a lot of experience and are doing something pretty simple.

Comment: Heap data is freed when a C program ends, which made me wonder how to maintain state after the Py-to-C call ended. Are you saying that the heap data remains intact even after the C call is finished? So, the heap data would be freed only either (1) manually or (2) when the Python program importing the module is terminated?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. The only "C program" here is CPython itself. That's who owns the heap, and that heap only goes away when your main Python script ends (or you call `sys.exit()`) and the CPython interpreter exists. Unless you do something silly (like calling `_exit()` from your C extension code—in which case it'll force the interpreter to exit), there is no exiting going on in your C code.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I was worried that I was just accessing freed-just-not-yet-modified memory.

Comment: Can you please show a small piece of code which wraps to `PyObject` an `intptr_t` variable (pointing to a C structure) and returns it to Python? And the reversed operation from `PyObject` to `intptr_t` and then C structure?

Comment: @Alex: You're asking, in a comment on an answer to someone else's problem, for me to reproduce something which is already available in the Cython, C-API, etc. tutorials. Why not just work through the tutorials yourself?

Comment: @abarnert The questions are not "owned" by people and I identified with this particular question. I consider redundant to write a new identical question asking for an example. I searched a lot before finding this question and haven't found tutorials or good documentation. I think it's nice to get help or advice from an experienced programmer, but I am not forcing you or anyone to do this of course!

Comment: @Alex: Again, the tutorials and reference documentation already have examples doing exactly what you want (except for the trivial cast to `intptr_t` part). If you haven't read that documentation, you're not going to understand any example; if you have, you already have an example.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/extension_types.html) for easy python-to-C bridging.  The documentation there has plenty of examples -- I linked to a page that explains how you how to build a state object of some sort and explains the memory issues.

Here's an example of an [AIO binding](https://github.com/ironport/shrapnel/blob/master/coro/aio.pyx) (github) written in cython/pyrex, an example of some fairly fancy I/O.  In my experience we've rolled custom objects that marshal down to disk in compressed format using I/O routines such as this -- in memory the cython code takes care of dealing with what is visible to python (e.g. custom rolled [socket object](https://github.com/ironport/shrapnel/blob/master/coro/socket.pyx))

My best advice is for you to search around for `.pyx` examples and you'll find some stuff that should inspire a solution for you.

I'll also agree with the other posters: ask yourself if moving to C is a needed thing since extension types are going to add complexity to your whole system.

Comment: Thanks B Evans. Cython is a good option but I have pre-existing C code already so a C extension would work best for me.